# How to get parent directory relative to an absolute path

Tags: php, directory, path

I am trying to require a file in PHP that is itself a required file. The path to the directory should be **../../includes/database.php**. But instead it is trying to go up two directories from the initial file requiring this second one.

I have found out that **__DIR__** can be used to get the absolute directory of the file. However I still cannot link to the correct directory using something like:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../../includes/database.php');
```

Is there some way to get a directory relative from this **DIR** path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
chdir('../');
echo getcwd();
```

Comment: that will navigate up one level - use additional `../` to go further up

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../database.php');
```

Comment: So simple, yet so elegant. I don't know why I didn't think of this, but I love you.